# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.CodeStream.newArray

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, lombok, spring-tools-4

**Environment**
jdk1.8 
spring-tool-suite4

**Issue**
cannot debug the project because of the eclipse java problem.

**Keywords**
codegen.TypeAnnotationCodeStream.newArray

**Detail**

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".

Contains: Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'goodslist'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.CodeStream.newArray(CodeStream.java:6096)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.TypeAnnotationCodeStream.newArray(TypeAnnotationCodeStream.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ArrayInitializer.generateCode(ArrayInitializer.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ArrayInitializer.generateCode(ArrayInitializer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ReturnStatement.generateCode(ReturnStatement.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.generateCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.generateCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:145)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key information in the log is "**ArrayInitializer**".

my solution is convert code below

```
  @Builder.Default
  private String[] attrValueIdPairs = {""};
```

to

```
  @Builder.Default
  private String[] attrValueIdPairs = new String[]{""};
```

eclipse error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be your problem?
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383624

There is alot of text in the bug report, but it mentions "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.CodeStream.newArray" and Nulls on a few occassions.

The bug is labelled as fixed. Maybe double check your versions, you may need to update your Eclipse version...